# What is the relationship between amplitude and the distance from the source of a water wave?

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves

Attempt of the relation: Intensity $I \propto \frac{1}{r^2}$ and $I \propto A^2$.
 So $A^2 \propto \frac{1}{r^2} \implies A \propto \frac{1}{r}$

Is it correct?

Comment: This is correct for spherical waves, i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not correct.  Think about why it is that $I \propto r^{-2}$ for (say) light or sound waves.  There's something fundamentally different about water waves that changes this relationship.

Other than that, the rest of your logic is correct.

Comment: Wave-fronts of sound waves and light waves spread radially outward in the form of spheres, whereas water waves are spread in circles

Comment: @Gopal:  That's true; now take it further.  How does the fact that sound & light waves move out in spheres lead to the fact that $I \propto 1/r^2$?

Comment: so this is how I derived it, $I = \frac{P}{2\pi r}\\\ \implies I \propto \frac{1}{r} \\\  \implies A \propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}$

Comment: @Gopal:  nicely done.